# GWT client - server SimpleDateFormat changes timezone to default

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-parsing

I'm using GWT RPC to send a string containing a date from the client to the server (it has to be this way, because it's on a request header).

On the server side I parse that string with SimpleDateFormat and make the logic I want.

I'm setting both my cell phone and computer to different time zones, and will use hosted mode and running the test project on tom cat.

Here's the code:

Client:

```
DateTimeFormat dtf = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
Date date = new Date();

System.out.println("client: " + date.toString());
System.out.println("client: " + dtf.format(date));
builder.setHeader("Date1", dtf.format(date));
```

Server:

```
String dateHeader = request.getHeader("Date1");
System.out.println("Server date header from client: " + dateHeader);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");

System.out.println("x = " + sdf.parse(dateHeader));
System.out.println("Timezone = " + df.getTimeZone().getDisplayName());
```

Result:

**Hosted Mode**
client: Wed Apr 11 17:29:49 NOVST 2012
client: 2012-04-11 17:29:49 +0700
Server date header from client: 2012-04-11 17:29:49 +0700
x = Wed Apr 11 17:29:49 NOVST 2012

---

**TomCat**

1. Using PC: Client, and server have the same time.

(Can't see the print of the client, obviously)

Server date header from client: 2012-04-11 17:31:37 +0700
x = Wed Apr 11 17:31:37 NOVST 2012

1. Cellphone client, has a different from the server.

Server date header from client: 2012-04-11 15:34:35 +0500
x = Wed Apr 11 17:34:35 NOVST 2012

Conclusion:
SimpleDateFormat ignores the Timezone that comes on the string. I don't want that! I want this to work properly. How can I make this work? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` doesn't ignore the timezone, as it has adjusted the time, parsing *15:34:35 +0500* into *17:34:35 NOVST* (where *NOVST* is +0700, the local timezone), it's just that `java.util.Date` is only a timestamp from Epoch and has no notion of a timezone (see the javadoc: everything is relative to the *local* timezone).

If you want to get the timezone of the client on the server-side, you'll have to parse the timezone field out of the serialized date (you could split on spaces, keep the last part –the timezone part– and pass it to [`java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone%28java.lang.String%29) prefixed with `GMT`).
Alternatively, you can use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) whose `DateTime` type keeps track of the timezone info; something like:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");

DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime(dateHeader);
System.out.println("x = " + fmt.print(dt));
System.out.println("Timezone = " + dt.getZone().toTimeZone().getDisplayName());
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. I was thinking about those two options, separate the timezone, or use JodaTime. I am already trying JodaTime, and it works well on hosted mode, but I can't seem to make it work on a tomcat instance.